# Publishing multiple data at a time

Tags: c++, function, callback

I have a header file which has a list of macros in the following format `#define <name_of_error> <word>,<bit> "<name_of_error>`

Following is a part of the header file -

```
#define CAMERA_ERROR 0,0, "CAMERA_ERROR"
#define IMAGE_NOT_DISPLAYING 0,1, "IMAGE_NOT_DISPLAYING"
#define CHANGE_IMAGE_CONSISTENCY 1,2, "CHANGE_IMAGE_CONSISTENCY"
```

Now I have a cpp source file where I have created a function `pubError` and pass header file information as arguments -

```
void pubError(int word, int bit, string name_of_error)
{
  // Body of the function
}
```

I have a callback function and I try to call the function `pubError` from within it (and passing `name_of_error`) like following -

```
void sensorCallback(const diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticArrayPtr &msg)
{
  msg->status[0].level == diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus::ERROR
  this->sc_.pubError(CAMERA_ERROR);
}
```

In this way I am able to publish only 1 error at a particular time. How can I publish multiple errors from the header file through the function `pubError`?

Comment: If you mean through a single call to `pubError`, you can't unless there are other overloads for `pubError` you haven't shown or the scheme used supports the combination of errors somehow, using a mechanism you haven't shown. Have you tried calling `pubError` multiple times? You should be looking at the library documentation or asking the library publisher.

Comment: It works by calling `pubError` multiple times. But I want to call `pubError` single time. The concept behind this code is everytime the `DiagnosticStatus` is `ERROR`, `pubError` function is called to publish the `name_of_error`. Each `name_of_error` is associated with unique `word` and bit` combination. In real time the `DiagnosticStatus` can change to `ERROR` for multiple errors mentioned in the header file. I am looking for a way to publish them all with a single `pubError` call.

Comment: The only way to accomplish what you want is to change/overload `pubError()` to accept an array of errors, where each error is a `struct`/`class` containing your 3 values.  And BTW, your `#define` macros are missing a required `,` in between the 2nd and 3rd values.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this. Assuming you don't want to change your `#define`s, you could change your `pubError` function as follows:

```
struct Error { int e1; int e2; std::string error; };
void pubError(std::vector<Error> errors)
{
    for (auto e : errors) std::cout << e.error.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

You could then invoke it as such:

```
#define CAMERA_ERROR 0,0, "CAMERA_ERROR"
#define IMAGE_NOT_DISPLAYING 0,1, "IMAGE_NOT_DISPLAYING"
#define CHANGE_IMAGE_CONSISTENCY 1,2, "CHANGE_IMAGE_CONSISTENCY"

pubError({ { CAMERA_ERROR }, { IMAGE_NOT_DISPLAYING } });
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you @mnistic . But my header file contains a list of 60 errors and the list may change from time to time, is there any other way to invoke `pubError`?

Comment: Yes. How can I change the array of errors automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? Can you write how you would like to invoke it?

Comment: I am assuming that if the header files has 50 macros, then invoking would be like - ` pubError ({{CAMERA_ERROR}, {IMAGE_NOT_DISPLAYING},{CHANGE_IMAGE_CONSISTENCY},........}); . Right? Now if my macros list changes, then every time I have to change the invoking? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well yes, if you add errors you have to update the code, but you have to do that any way you look at it. You cannot have code that will automatically know which error it is handling simply because you added another macro, some other code needs to tell it "this is the error." I'm still not clear on exactly what you're after.

Comment: The concept behind this code is every time the `DiagnosticStatus` is `ERROR`, `pubError` function is called to publish the `name_of_error`. Each `name_of_error` is associated with unique `word` and `bit` combination. Now the `DiagnosticStatus` can change to `ERROR` because of more than 1 error (listed in the header file). I want to publish them all with 1 call